# Loading/dipping into CodeIgniter from Zend

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

I got hold of a dip into CI from CI forums and websites, which I have working. Basically; I have a fully working system in CodeIgniter, I have run tests that show a standard PHP file on the same server can access the classes and libraries that I made available.

One of the other legacy systems runs on Zend, and throws an exception when it incudes the CodeIgniter files. I can't get past:

```
$BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
```

in the dip file, with a long error being thrown by Zend. It throws (among much other information):

```
exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'At least one error occurred including "Benchmark.php"; see includeErrors property'
```

Pretty much everything I can find on the internet finds ways to use the libraries from CodeIgniter, but that's the reverse of what I'm looking for. If I comment out the Benchmark loading, then it fails on Hooks, which leads me to believe that Zend has usurped or overloaded the `load_class()` function with its own, and is causing problems that way.

Has anybody gotten them working before?

Comment: To head-off the obvious: the following options are not available: it must work with the existing Zend, it's on PHP 5.2.16, yes I'm aware of what a cardinal sin that is, CI is 2.1.2 and no I can't switch libraries/frameworks/languages/plug in any other random solution not previously mentioned. Running on Debian 5. Again, no change available. Thanks.

Comment: In case anybody gets here because of the question: never solved. Ended up duplicating code across two systems.

Answer (score 0):

I can't directly answer the question, but I just stumbled over a bit of rotting code referencing an Exception's "includeErrors" property.

After some search, I can maybe give a bit of context to what you observed.

Behaviour exists in some versions of ZF1 , see http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2463

- if Zend_Loader includes a file
- and the mere act of including it results in some PHP error (very often that will be E_STRICT if for example some inherited method signature doesnt match, or maybe if file is not found),
- then it will throw an exception and add a "includeErrors" property to it